# how to reset UIButton background image mentioned in interface builder?

Tags: iphone, ios4, uibutton, xcode

I creating an iPhone application, set background image for UIButton using interface builder, then i changed the background image for that UIButton programmatically. Now i need to restore the background programmatically which i have used already(used in interface builder).

Answer (score 1):

After you change the background image programmatically, you either need to call `-viewDidLoad` (probably after calling `-viewDidUnload`) to reset the background, or change it again progammatically. The `UIImage` doesn't remember it's previous background, so there is no easier way to "restore" the setting.